# Class extends unworking with EasyAdmin 3 in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony4, easyadmin

I'm trying to make Web App with Symfony and I need an Admin side. But, it won't work and I don't see any answer for my problem on any site. Here we go :

I have this problem each time I try link a CRUD in my menu :

`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to find the controller related to the "App\Controller\Admin\Producteur" Entity; did you forget to extend "EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController"?").`

And if I read it carefully I forgot an `extends` in one of files but I don't see where. More of that, I generate these files with the bundle and I have this error just after that and other people who make the same protocol than me don't have this error.

I gave you my different files if you see something, because I can't just be blocked and don't finish my internship.

Producteur.php

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ProducteurRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProducteurRepository::class)
 */
class Producteur
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=PtManufacturer::class, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="id_manufacturer", referencedColumnName="id_manufacturer")
     */
    private $Nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $courriel_User;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $courriel_Corresp;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $TVA_Appl;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $Num_TVA;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $Pied_De_Doc;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $adresse1_E;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $adresse2_E;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=5)
     */
    private $CP_E;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $Ville_E;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $adresse1_F;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $adresse2_F;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=5)
     */
    private $CP_F;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $Ville_F;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $Num_Tel;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?PtManufacturer
    {
        return $this->Nom;
    }

    public function setNom(PtManufacturer $Nom): self
    {
        $this->Nom = $Nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCourrielUser(): ?string
    {
        return $this->courriel_User;
    }

    public function setCourrielUser(string $courriel_User): self
    {
        $this->courriel_User = $courriel_User;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCourrielCorresp(): ?string
    {
        return $this->courriel_Corresp;
    }

    public function setCourrielCorresp(string $courriel_Corresp): self
    {
        $this->courriel_Corresp = $courriel_Corresp;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTVAAppl(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->TVA_Appl;
    }

    public function setTVAAppl(bool $TVA_Appl): self
    {
        $this->TVA_Appl = $TVA_Appl;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNumTVA(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Num_TVA;
    }

    public function setNumTVA(string $Num_TVA): self
    {
        $this->Num_TVA = $Num_TVA;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPiedDeDoc(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Pied_De_Doc;
    }

    public function setPiedDeDoc(string $Pied_De_Doc): self
    {
        $this->Pied_De_Doc = $Pied_De_Doc;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdresse1E(): ?string
    {
        return $this->adresse1_E;
    }

    public function setAdresse1E(string $adresse1_E): self
    {
        $this->adresse1_E = $adresse1_E;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdresse2E(): ?string
    {
        return $this->adresse2_E;
    }

    public function setAdresse2E(?string $adresse2_E): self
    {
        $this->adresse2_E = $adresse2_E;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCPE(): ?string
    {
        return $this->CP_E;
    }

    public function setCPE(string $CP_E): self
    {
        $this->CP_E = $CP_E;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVilleE(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Ville_E;
    }

    public function setVilleE(string $Ville_E): self
    {
        $this->Ville_E = $Ville_E;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdresse1F(): ?string
    {
        return $this->adresse1_F;
    }

    public function setAdresse1F(string $adresse1_F): self
    {
        $this->adresse1_F = $adresse1_F;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdresse2F(): ?string
    {
        return $this->adresse2_F;
    }

    public function setAdresse2F(?string $adresse2_F): self
    {
        $this->adresse2_F = $adresse2_F;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCPF(): ?string
    {
        return $this->CP_F;
    }

    public function setCPF(string $CP_F): self
    {
        $this->CP_F = $CP_F;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVilleF(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Ville_F;
    }

    public function setVilleF(string $Ville_F): self
    {
        $this->Ville_F = $Ville_F;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNumTel(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Num_Tel;
    }

    public function setNumTel(string $Num_Tel): self
    {
        $this->Num_Tel = $Num_Tel;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

ProducteurCrudController.php

```
namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Producteur;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;

class ProducteurCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Producteur::class;
    }

    /*
    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            IdField::new('id'),
            TextField::new('title'),
            TextEditorField::new('description'),
        ];
    }
    */
}
```

DashboardController.php

```
namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Dashboard;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\MenuItem;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractDashboardController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class DashboardController extends AbstractDashboardController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin", name="admin")
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return parent::index();
    }

    public function configureDashboard(): Dashboard
    {
        return Dashboard::new()
            ->setTitle('Backoffice');
    }

    public function configureMenuItems(): iterable
    {
        return[
            MenuItem::linktoDashboard('Dashboard', 'fa fa-home'),
            MenuItem::linkToCrud('Producteur', 'fas fa-list', Producteur::class),
        ];
    }
}
```

menu.html.twig

```
{% macro render_menu_item(item) %}
    {% if item.isMenuSection %}
        {% if item.icon is not empty %}<i class="menu-icon fa-fw {{ item.icon }}"></i>{% endif %}
        <span class="{{ item.cssClass }}">{{ item.label }}</span>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{{ item.linkUrl }}" class="{{ item.cssClass }}" target="{{ item.linkTarget }}" rel="{{ item.linkRel }}" referrerpolicy="origin-when-cross-origin">
            {% if item.icon is not empty %}<i class="menu-icon fa-fw {{ item.icon }}"></i>{% endif %}
            <span>{{ item.label|raw }}</span>
            {% if item.hasSubItems %}<i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right treeview-icon"></i>{% endif %}
        </a>
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{% block main_menu_before %}{% endblock %}

<ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree" data-animation-speed="250">
    {% block main_menu %}
        {% for menuItem in ea.mainMenu.items %}
            {% block menu_item %}
                <li class="{{ menuItem.isMenuSection ? 'header' }} {{ menuItem.hasSubItems ? 'treeview' }} {{ ea.mainMenu.isSelected(menuItem) ? 'active' }} {{ ea.mainMenu.isExpanded(menuItem) ? 'active submenu-active' }}">
                    {{ _self.render_menu_item(menuItem) }}

                    {% if menuItem.hasSubItems %}
                        <ul class="treeview-menu">
                            {% for menuSubItem in menuItem.subItems %}
                                {% block menu_subitem %}
                                    <li class="{{ menuSubItem.isMenuSection ? 'header' }} {{ ea.mainMenu.isSelected(menuSubItem) ? 'active' }}">
                                        {{ _self.render_menu_item(menuSubItem) }}
                                    </li>
                                {% endblock menu_subitem %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    {% endif %}
                </li>
            {% endblock menu_item %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock main_menu %}
</ul>

{% block main_menu_after %}{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you see your controller ProducteurCrudController in routes with : `php bin/console debug:route --show-controllers` ?

Comment: No, I don't see it, I see the others but not that one.

Comment: Help Please ? I need to go forward in my project.

Answer (score 5):

You should add

```
use App\Entity\Producteur;
```

to your DashboardController.php file

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same problem with Symfony 4.4 LTS version. I solved it by upgrading my project to Symfony 5.2. It seems that it is not compatible with 4 anymore.

When I have time will try to create a reproducible issue. And hopefully a fix also.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller services need to be tagged with `ea.crud_controller`and `ea.dashboard_controller`. Or better, let's easyadmin configure them for you :

Check that you have `autoconfigure="true"` by default in Resources/config/services.xml :

```
<services>
    <defaults autowire="true" autoconfigure="false" ...>
    ...
```

Or add this:

```
<services>
    ...
    <prototype namespace="AppBundle\Controller\Admin\"
        resource="../../Controller/Admin"
        autoconfigure="true">
    </prototype>
```

You can check that the tags are well added by running:

`php bin/console debug:container --tag=ea.crud_controller`